# Problemas de rendimiento

Tags: java

**Problematica**

Tengo un programa en el cual hago el algoritmo de N Reinas de forma gráfica para que sea un juego, todo el programa funciona bien y cuando las reinas están colocadas de forma correcta todo corre perfecto, pero mi problema empieza de la siguiente manera.

Cuando muevo las piezas tengo un arreglo en donde me debe de representar la posición actual de la pieza en el tablero (Todo lo que digo lo imprimo en el programa) pero de vez en cuando cuando llego a mover las piezas muy rápido no me hace las operaciones de manera adecuada y aveces me pone mal el arreglo, esto no se nota tanto desde la computadora que tengo ya que tiene buenos componentes pero cuando corro el programa en una computadora común comienza a generar problemas con eso.

Pienso que el principal problema son los métodos de `mouseReleased` y `mousePressed` en donde ejecuto las operaciones que se encargan del arreglo que les menciono, no se como podría mejorar el rendimiento del programa para que todo se ejecutara de mejor manera, tanto de esos métodos que les menciono como e resto de métodos del programa, así que si pudieran ayudarme con eso les estaría muy agradecido.

> El método de `posicion` esta mal optimizado en gran medida y en muchas ocaciones genera errores al posicionar elementos.

**RESUMEN**

El programa falla en ocasiones aunque todas las reinas estén colocadas de manera adecuada, la única forma de que el programa no falle en lo absoluto es mover las piezas de forma muy lenta y llega a dar el mensaje de `Felicidades, completaste el juego de N reinas` en cambio con el error que sucede en ocasiones el programa simplemente lanza donde un mensaje mencionando el error aunque esto no sea correcto.

```
package otraprueba;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class OtraPrueba extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    static int reinas = 0;
    String[][] algoritmo = new String[reinas][reinas];
    String[][] comprobacion = new String[reinas][reinas];
    int count = 0;
    int anchoAlto = 50;
    int margen = 25;
    int espacio = 50;
    JPanel jpanel = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
    JLabel ex = new JLabel();
    JLabel label[] = new JLabel[reinas];
    JLabel tablero[][] = new JLabel[reinas][reinas];
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1);

    String[] parts;
    int x, y, cooX, cooY, newI, newJ;

    JButton boton1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reinas = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad de reinas"));
        OtraPrueba op = new OtraPrueba();
        op.setBounds(0, 0, (60 * reinas), (60 * reinas));
        op.setVisible(true);
        op.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public OtraPrueba() {
        // Declaracion de reinas
        for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
            label[i] = new JLabel();
            // r + r + r + r
            label[i].setBounds(margen + (espacio * i), margen, anchoAlto, anchoAlto);
            label[i].setText("Q" + (i + 1));
            label[i].setForeground(Color.red);
            label[i].setBorder(border);
            label[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            label[i].addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
                    arrastreReina(evt);
                }
            });
            label[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
                    arregloTablero(evt);
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
                    valoresIniciales(evt);
                }
            });
            jpanel.add(label[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < algoritmo.length; j++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    algoritmo[i][j] = Integer.toString((margen + (espacio * j))) + "|" + Integer.toString(margen);
                } else {
                    algoritmo[i][j] = "0|0";
                }
            }
        }

        // Declaracion del tablero
        for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tablero.length; j++) {
                tablero[i][j] = new JLabel();
                tablero[i][j].setBounds(margen + (espacio * i), margen + (espacio * j), anchoAlto, anchoAlto);
                tablero[i][j].setBorder(border);

                if ((i % 2 == 0) == (j % 2 == 0)) {
                    tablero[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                } else {
                    tablero[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
                }

                tablero[i][j].setOpaque(true);
                tablero[i][j].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                jpanel.add(tablero[i][j]);
            }
        }

        // Declaracion del boton
        setLayout(null);
        boton1 = new JButton("Finalizar");
        boton1.setBounds(25, 3, 90, 20);
        jpanel.add(boton1);
        boton1.addActionListener(this);

        ex.setBounds(margen, margen, anchoAlto, anchoAlto);
        jpanel.add(ex);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == boton1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < comprobacion.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < comprobacion.length; j++) {
                    if (algoritmo[i][j].equals("0|0")) {
                        comprobacion[i][j] = "*";
                    } else {
                        comprobacion[i][j] = "+";
                    }
                }
            }

            imprimirArreglo(comprobacion);

            int contUno = 0;
            int contDos = 0;
            int contTres = 0;

            int diagS, diagI;

            for (int i = 0; i < comprobacion.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < comprobacion.length; j++) {
                    // Comprobacion de filas
                    if (comprobacion[i][j].equals("+")) {
                        contUno++;
                        if (contUno == 2) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Existe más de una reina en una fila");
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Comprobacion de columnas
                    if (comprobacion[j][i].equals("+")) {
                        contDos++;
                        if (contDos == 2) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Existe más de una reina en una columna");
                            break;
                        }

                        // Comprobacion de diagonales
                        diagS = j - 1;
                        diagI = j + 1;

                        if (diagS < 0) {
                            diagS = 0;
                        } else if (diagI >= comprobacion.length) {
                            diagI = (comprobacion.length - 1);
                        }

                        System.out.println("S/I: " + diagS + "/" + diagI);

                        if (i < comprobacion.length - 1) {
                            if (comprobacion[diagS][i + 1].equals("+") || comprobacion[diagI][i + 1].equals("+")) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "En alguna diagnoal de las reinas existe mas de una reina");
                                contTres = 2;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (contUno == 2 || contDos == 2 || contTres == 2) {
                    break;
                }
                contUno = 0;
                contDos = 0;
                contTres = 0;
            }

            if (contUno == 0 && contDos == 0 && contTres == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Felicidades, completaste el juego de N Reinas");
            }
        }
    }

    public void arrastreReina(MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
            ((JLabel) evt.getSource()).setLocation(posicion(evt)[0], posicion(evt)[1]);
        }
    }

    public void valoresIniciales(MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
            this.newI = (posicion(evt)[1] - 25) / 50;
            this.newJ = (posicion(evt)[0] - 25) / 50;
            x = posicion(evt)[0];
            y = posicion(evt)[1];
            System.out.println("INI X/Y: " + this.newI + "/" + this.newJ);
            System.out.println("X/Y: " + x + "/" + y);
        }
    }

    public void arregloTablero(MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
            int newX = (posicion(evt)[0] - x) / 50;
            int newY = (posicion(evt)[1] - y) / 50;

            System.out.println("pos X/Y: " + posicion(evt)[0] + "/" + posicion(evt)[1]);
            System.out.println("newX: " + newX + "\nnewY: " + newY);

            algoritmo[newI][newJ] = "0|0";
            System.out.println("newI/newJ: " + newI + "/" + newJ);
            algoritmo[newI + newY][newJ + newX] = Integer.toString(posicion(evt)[0]) + "|" + Integer.toString(posicion(evt)[1]);

            count++;
            System.out.println("Movimientos: " + count);
            imprimirArreglo(algoritmo);
        }
    }

    public void imprimirArreglo(String[][] arreglo) {
        for (String[] arreglo1 : arreglo) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arreglo.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(arreglo1[j] + "    ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }

    public int[] posicion(MouseEvent evt) {
        int newX, newY;

        // Variables de entorno X
        String conX = Integer.toString(evt.getXOnScreen());
        String ultimoX = conX.substring(conX.length() - 2, conX.length());

        int primerosMenosUltimosX = Integer.parseInt(ultimoX);

        if (primerosMenosUltimosX < 25) {
            newX = 25 + (evt.getXOnScreen() - espacio - primerosMenosUltimosX);
        } else if (primerosMenosUltimosX < 75) {
            newX = 75 + (evt.getXOnScreen() - espacio - primerosMenosUltimosX);
        } else {
            newX = 25 + ((evt.getXOnScreen() - espacio + 100) - primerosMenosUltimosX);
        }

        // Variables de entorno Y
        String conY = Integer.toString(evt.getYOnScreen());
        String ultimoY = conY.substring(conY.length() - 2, conY.length());

        int primerosMenosUltimosY = Integer.parseInt(ultimoY);

        if (primerosMenosUltimosY < 25) {
            newY = 25 + (evt.getYOnScreen() - espacio - primerosMenosUltimosY);
        } else if (primerosMenosUltimosY < 75) {
            newY = 75 + (evt.getYOnScreen() - espacio - primerosMenosUltimosY);
        } else {
            newY = 25 + ((evt.getYOnScreen() - espacio + 100) - primerosMenosUltimosY);
        }

        int retorno[] = {newX, newY};

        return retorno;
    }

}
```

Comment: El problema esta en el calculo de las celdas, en ocasiones se obtienen valores incorrectos los cuales no puedes obtener del arreglo bidimensional, de hecho en valoresIniciales() estas calculando incorrectamente el valor de x y y (newI ynewJ).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

En realidad hay un problema que se genera al liberar el mouse  mouseReleased() > arregloTablero() y es :

> java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

el cual se genera en cuando liberas el mouse e intentas modificar un valor en una posición no existente del array:

```
algoritmo[newI][newJ] = "0|0";
```

En realidad debes usar los valores de `newI` y `newJ` calculados pero a partir del método `posicion()`:

```
public void arregloTablero(MouseEvent evt) {
 if (evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {

            int position[] = posicion(evt);
            int newX = posicion(evt)[0];
            int newY = posicion(evt)[1];      
            newI = (newX - 25) / 50;
            newJ = (newY - 25) / 50;
            //int newX = (posicion(evt)[0] - x) / 50;
            //int newY = (posicion(evt)[1] - y) / 50;                
            ...
            ...                
            //* error algoritmo[newI][newJ] = "0|0";
            //Reemplaza con valor de posición.
            algoritmo[newJ][newI] = newX + "|" + newY;
            ...
            ...
```

Los valores iniciales "0|0" deben ser reemplazados dentro del método `valoresIniciales()` :

```
algoritmo[newJ][newI] = "0|0";
```

**El problema en realidad es el calculo de las celdas ya que en ocasiones se obtienen valores incorrectos o negativos los cuales no existen en el array!**

Tienes algunos problemas en los método `arregloTablero()`, `posicion()`, incluso en la impresión de los valores del arreglo se realiza incorrectamente porque deben insertarse `algoritmo[newJ][newI]` en lugar de `algoritmo[newI][newJ]` para que funcione correctamente el método `imprimirArreglo()`:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class OtraPrueba extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    static int reinas = 3;
    String[][] algoritmo = new String[reinas][reinas];
    String[][] comprobacion = new String[reinas][reinas];
    int count = 0;
    int anchoAlto = 50; //Alto celda
    int margen = 25; //Margen superior, donde se posiciona botón finalizar.
    int espacio = 50; //Ancho celda
    JPanel jpanel = (JPanel) this.getContentPane();
    JLabel ex = new JLabel();
    JLabel label[] = new JLabel[reinas];
    JLabel tablero[][] = new JLabel[reinas][reinas];
    Border border = BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black, 1);

    String[] parts;
    int x, y, cooX, cooY, newI, newJ;

    JButton boton1;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        reinas =  Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Ingrese la cantidad de reinas"));
        OtraPrueba op = new OtraPrueba();
        op.setBounds(0, 0, (60 * reinas), (60 * reinas));
        op.setVisible(true);
        op.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public OtraPrueba() {
        // Declaracion de reinas
        for (int i = 0; i < label.length; i++) {
            label[i] = new JLabel();
            // r + r + r + r
            label[i].setBounds(margen + (espacio * i), margen, anchoAlto, anchoAlto);
            label[i].setText("Q" + (i + 1));
            label[i].setForeground(Color.red);
            label[i].setBorder(border);
            label[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            label[i].addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent evt) {
                    arrastreReina(evt);
                }
            });
            label[i].addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent evt) {
                    //System.out.println("mouseReleased " + evt.toString());
                    arregloTablero(evt);
                }

                @Override
                public void mousePressed(MouseEvent evt) {
                    //System.out.println("mousePressed " + evt.toString());
                    valoresIniciales(evt);
                }
            });
            jpanel.add(label[i]);

            for (int j = 0; j < algoritmo.length; j++) {
                if (i == 0) {
                    algoritmo[i][j] = Integer.toString((margen + (espacio * j))) + "|" + Integer.toString(margen);
                } else {
                    algoritmo[i][j] = "0|0";
                }
            }
        }

        // Declaracion del tablero
        for (int i = 0; i < tablero.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < tablero.length; j++) {
                tablero[i][j] = new JLabel();
                tablero[i][j].setBounds(margen + (espacio * i), margen + (espacio * j), anchoAlto, anchoAlto);
                tablero[i][j].setBorder(border);

                if ((i % 2 == 0) == (j % 2 == 0)) {
                    tablero[i][j].setBackground(Color.white);
                } else {
                    tablero[i][j].setBackground(Color.black);
                }

                tablero[i][j].setOpaque(true);
                tablero[i][j].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                jpanel.add(tablero[i][j]);
            }
        }

        // Declaracion del boton
        setLayout(null);
        boton1 = new JButton("Finalizar");
        boton1.setBounds(25, 3, 90, 20);
        jpanel.add(boton1);
        boton1.addActionListener(this);

        ex.setBounds(margen, margen, anchoAlto, anchoAlto);
        jpanel.add(ex);
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (e.getSource() == boton1) {
            for (int i = 0; i < comprobacion.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < comprobacion.length; j++) {
                    if (algoritmo[i][j].equals("0|0")) {
                        comprobacion[i][j] = "*";
                    } else {
                        comprobacion[i][j] = "+";
                    }
                }
            }

            imprimirArreglo(comprobacion);

            int contUno = 0;
            int contDos = 0;
            int contTres = 0;

            int diagS, diagI;

            for (int i = 0; i < comprobacion.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < comprobacion.length; j++) {
                    // Comprobacion de filas
                    if (comprobacion[i][j].equals("+")) {
                        contUno++;
                        if (contUno == 2) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Existe más de una reina en una fila");
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Comprobacion de columnas
                    if (comprobacion[j][i].equals("+")) {
                        contDos++;
                        if (contDos == 2) {
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Existe más de una reina en una columna");
                            break;
                        }

                        // Comprobacion de diagonales
                        diagS = j - 1;
                        diagI = j + 1;

                        if (diagS < 0) {
                            diagS = 0;
                        } else if (diagI >= comprobacion.length) {
                            diagI = (comprobacion.length - 1);
                        }

                        System.out.println("S/I: " + diagS + "/" + diagI);

                        if (i < comprobacion.length - 1) {
                            if (comprobacion[diagS][i + 1].equals("+") || comprobacion[diagI][i + 1].equals("+")) {
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "En alguna diagonal de las reinas existe mas de una reina");
                                contTres = 2;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                if (contUno == 2 || contDos == 2 || contTres == 2) {
                    break;
                }
                contUno = 0;
                contDos = 0;
                contTres = 0;
            }

            if (contUno == 0 && contDos == 0 && contTres == 0) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Felicidades, completaste el juego de N Reinas");
            }
        }
    }

    public void arrastreReina(MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
            ((JLabel) evt.getSource()).setLocation(posicion(evt)[0], posicion(evt)[1]);
          }
    }

    public void valoresIniciales(MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
            this.newI = (posicion(evt)[0] - 25) / 50;
            this.newJ = (posicion(evt)[1] - 25) / 50;

            x = posicion(evt)[0];
            y = posicion(evt)[1];
            System.out.println("* iniciales INI X/Y: " + this.newI + "/" + this.newJ);

            //Reemplaza valor inicial con "0|0"
            algoritmo[newJ][newI] = "0|0";
            imprimirArreglo(algoritmo);
        }
    }


    //Posibles valores en array.
    // 25/25  25/75  25/125
    // 25/75  75/75  125/75
    // 25/125 75/125 125/125

        public void arregloTablero(MouseEvent evt) {
        if (evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {

            int[] posicion = posicion(evt);            
            int newX = posicion(evt)[0];
            int newY = posicion(evt)[1];

            newI = (newX - 25) / 50;
            newJ = (newY - 25) / 50;

            System.out.println("*finales newI/newJ: " + newI + "/" + newJ);

             //Reemplaza con valor de posición.
            algoritmo[newJ][newI] = newX + "|" + newY;

            count++;
            System.out.println("Movimientos: " + count);
            imprimirArreglo(algoritmo);
        }
    }

    public void imprimirArreglo(String[][] arreglo) {
        System.out.println("/------------/");      
        for (String[] elemento : arreglo) {
            for (int j = 0; j < arreglo.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(elemento[j] + "    ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
          System.out.println("/------------/");
    }


   public int[] posicion(MouseEvent evt) {
    JLabel label = (JLabel) evt.getSource();
    Point labelLocation = label.getLocation();
    int newX = labelLocation.x + evt.getX();
    int newY = labelLocation.y + evt.getY();

    newX = Math.min(Math.max(0, ((newX - margen) / espacio)), reinas - 1);
    newY = Math.min(Math.max(0, ((newY - margen) / espacio)), reinas - 1);    
    newX = (newX * espacio) + margen;
    newY = (newY * espacio) + margen;   

    int retorno[] = {newX, newY};
    return retorno;

}



}
```

Estos son ejemplos del funcionamiento así como la impresión de los valores en el array y su comprobación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Pero ahora el problema es que con las modificaciones que me indicas el arreglo que comprueba que las reinas esten correctamente colocadas no mueva las piezas dentro del mismo arreglo que me sirve para comprobar dichas condicionales por lo que aunque esten bien acomodadas las reinas siempre da error.

Comment: @ASASCED ok es necesario comprobar el arreglo imprimiendo las posiciones,te refieres a  : 25|25    75|25    125|25    
0|0    0|0    0|0    
0|0    0|0    0|0

Comment: asi es, a ese me refiero porque despues en todas las posiciones en donde sea diferente de 0|0 las combierte a + y las que tienen 0|0 a * por lo que de esa forma yo al pasar el arreglo por las condicionales me sirve para saber si las reinas estan acomodadas de manera adecuada o no.

Comment: @ASASCED ok dame un poco de tiempo y más tarde modifico para que imprima la información que requieres.

Comment: ok, esperare, ejecuta el codigo original para que puedas observar la conversion de el arreglo original al que ocupo en la comprobacion de las reinas

Comment: @ASASCED Listo, al revisar nuevamente el código me percate que en la impresión de los valores en el array en ocasiones tenía falla, esto debido a que se insertaban incorrectamente los valores, saludos!

Comment: @Jorgesys Además de re-copiar el método `posicion()` de la respuesta que yo escribí ¿Qué mas has hecho?

Comment: @ffernandez ¿es afirmación o pregunta? ¿es idéntico tu método al mío? te puedo asegurar que no, sinceramente no he visto tu respuesta la cual solo indica el método posicion() como el problema, en realidad hay más detalles a corregir, incluso la inserción de los valores a imprimir. Lo que realice es tratar brindar una solución completa al OP para que resolviera el problema planteado en la pregunta.

Comment: @Jorgesys es afirmación. Ya vi desde ayer que copiaste mi método en tu edición. De hecho, tu primera respuesta no tenía nada que ver con la de ahora (desde que me copiaste, claro). Y sí, el problema es únicamente en `posicion()`. Como ya dije en un principio, con el código original del OP y mi función `posicion()` el programa funciona perfectamente. En tu aporte además de confundir al OP has movido del lugar la asignacion de algoritmo[][] = "0|0" quedando un código "diferente", pero que hace el mismo trabajo. El mérito para tí claro ;)

Comment: "Corrigiendo" el método posicion() no se soluciona el problema. No se creo que este confundiendo estoy dando solución al problema.

Comment: Claro que se soluciona, [aquí](https://pastebin.com/SdqTEcnE) tienes el codigo original del OP con mi funcion `posicion()` funcionando perfectamente. Con cualquier diff checker puedes comprobar que el resto del código es examente el original del OP.

Comment: Ok, puedes comentarle directamente a el OP que solo con poner tu método funciona, aunque te aseguro que no es así, nuevamente te repito faltan otras correcciones.

Answer (score 1):

El problema está en la función `posicion()`. Me es complicado entender el sentido de tu  implementación donde haces tratamientos de Strings, cuando realmente sólo hay que hacer operaciones matemáticas.

Ademas al usar los métodos getXOnScreen() la posicion que obtienes se ve afectada por la posición de la ventana.

Prueba con esta implementación:

```
public int[] posicion(MouseEvent evt) {
    JLabel label = (JLabel) evt.getSource();
    Point labelLocation = label.getLocation();

    int x = labelLocation.x + evt.getX();
    int y = labelLocation.y + evt.getY();

    // Obtener numero de casilla x, y
    x = (x - margen) / espacio;
    y = (y - margen) / espacio;

    // No posicionar fuera del tablero
    x = Math.min(Math.max(0, x), reinas - 1);
    y = Math.min(Math.max(0, y), reinas - 1);

    // Revertir posicion exacta de casilla
    x = (x * espacio) + margen;
    y = (y * espacio) + margen;

    return new int[] { x, y };
}
```

**Añado explicación**

El motivo por el que no debes usar `evt.getXOnScreen()` para este caso es porque esa función devuelve la posición donde se hace click respecto a la pantalla. Es decir, devuelve la posición del cursor desde la esquina superior izquierda de la pantalla. Por lo tanto, la posición del JFrame en el escritorio afectará a este valor.

Por otro lado, con `evt.getX()` la posición se obtiene relativa al componente que recibe el evento. En este caso, relativa al JLabel. Por ejemplo: Si evt.getX() devuelve 30, quiere decir que la pulsación se hizo a 30 píxeles desde el borde izquierdo del JLabel.

Es por eso que en mi solución, obtengo `evt.getX()` y le sumo la posición del JLabel `labelLocation.x` . Así sabrás de forma exacta en qué posición del tablero se hizo la pulsación.

Te muestro gráficamente la distancia que devuelve cada funcion si pulsamos el cursor en una zona de **Q2**, por ejemplo:

[image: Detalle de getXOnScreen() y getX()]

Siguendo tu implementación, debes tener en cuenta el margen inicial que aplicas al tablero para obtener la posición de la casilla pulsada.

Dicho esto, al ejecutar el código, mediante estas líneas obtenemos qué casilla se pulsó:

```
// Obtener numero de casilla x, y
x = (x - margen) / espacio; // Para el ejemplo x será 1
y = (y - margen) / espacio; // Para el ejemplo y será 0
```

Las siguientes 2 lineas comprueban que estos valores no sean inferior a 0 ni superior a reinas - 1 (por si el usuario arrastra la casilla por fuera del tablero)

Y finalmente convertimos la posición a la distancia para ubicar el JLabel en el tablero.

```
// Revertir posicion exacta de casilla
x = (x * espacio) + margen; // Para el ejemplo x será 75 (1 espacio + margen)
y = (y * espacio) + margen; // y será 25 (margen)
```

Como habrás comprobado, cambiando en tu código la implementación de `posicion()` por la que te he propuesto, funciona sin tener que realizar mas ajustes. Espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: ¿Crees poder detallar un poco mas tu respuesta? la verdad es que a pesar de que se que tenia ese error no entiendo porque al usar solamente `getX` y `getY` sin el `labelLocation` se mueven un poco raro las reinas por lo que termine usando el `getXOnScreen`

Comment: @ASASCED he editado la respuesta añadiendo una explicación. Espero que te ayude a comprenderlo.

Comment: Hola te comento nuevamente, corrigiendo el método posicion() , no soluciona el problema, como te he comentado hay más detalles a corregir.

Comment: Si no soluciona el problema, ¿Porqué lo has copiado tal cual a tu solución?. ¿Podrías detallar esos "detalles"?

Comment: Claro, revisa mi respuesta, ahí se describen, el código es completamente funcional para lo que se desea en la pregunta..

Answer (score 0):

Abro la aplicación e indico que quiero tres reinas. Ahora las muevo.

- Si el formulario permanece situado en la esquina superior izquierda,
  la aplicación funciona bien.
- Si el formulario lo mueves al centro de la pantalla y mueves una reina,
  la aplicación falla.

El motivo del fallo es el método que calcula la casilla a la que se mueve la reina

```
public void valoresIniciales(MouseEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
        this.newI = (posicion(evt)[1] - 25) / 50;
        this.newJ = (posicion(evt)[0] - 25) / 50;
        x = posicion(evt)[0];
        y = posicion(evt)[1];
        System.out.println("INI X/Y: " + this.newI + "/" + this.newJ);
        System.out.println("X/Y: " + x + "/" + y);
    }
}
```

Llama a posicion(evt)

```
public int[] posicion(MouseEvent evt) {
    int newX, newY;

    // Variables de entorno X
    String conX = Integer.toString(evt.getXOnScreen());
    String ultimoX = conX.substring(conX.length() - 2, conX.length());

    int primerosMenosUltimosX = Integer.parseInt(ultimoX);

    if (primerosMenosUltimosX < 25) {
        newX = 25 + (evt.getXOnScreen() - espacio - primerosMenosUltimosX);
    } else if (primerosMenosUltimosX < 75) {
        newX = 75 + (evt.getXOnScreen() - espacio - primerosMenosUltimosX);
    } else {
        newX = 25 + ((evt.getXOnScreen() - espacio + 100) - primerosMenosUltimosX);
    }

    // Variables de entorno Y
    String conY = Integer.toString(evt.getYOnScreen());
    String ultimoY = conY.substring(conY.length() - 2, conY.length());

    int primerosMenosUltimosY = Integer.parseInt(ultimoY);

    if (primerosMenosUltimosY < 25) {
        newY = 25 + (evt.getYOnScreen() - espacio - primerosMenosUltimosY);
    } else if (primerosMenosUltimosY < 75) {
        newY = 75 + (evt.getYOnScreen() - espacio - primerosMenosUltimosY);
    } else {
        newY = 25 + ((evt.getYOnScreen() - espacio + 100) - primerosMenosUltimosY);
    }

    int retorno[] = {newX, newY};

    return retorno;
}
```

Este método calcula la posición del ratón de la siguiente forma:

```
String conX = Integer.toString(evt.getXOnScreen());
```

Este método, desde una pantalla 1920x1080, cuando llevo el formulario
al centro de la pantalla, da valores para la X de 800-900 px.

```
this.newI = (900 - 25) / 50  --> 17
```

Como el valor de la casilla es 17, en arregloTablero te va a lanzar una excepción:

```
public void arregloTablero(MouseEvent evt) {
    if (evt.getSource() instanceof JLabel) {
        int newX = (posicion(evt)[0] - x) / 50;
        int newY = (posicion(evt)[1] - y) / 50;

        System.out.println("pos X/Y: " + posicion(evt)[0] + "/" + posicion(evt)[1]);
        System.out.println("newX: " + newX + "\nnewY: " + newY);

        algoritmo[newI][newJ] = "0|0";
        System.out.println("newI/newJ: " + newI + "/" + newJ);
        algoritmo[newI + newY][newJ + newX] = Integer.toString(posicion(evt)[0]) + "|" + Integer.toString(posicion(evt)[1]);

        count++;
        System.out.println("Movimientos: " + count);
        imprimirArreglo(algoritmo);
    }
}
```

Concretamente en esta línea:

```
algoritmo[newI][newJ] = "0|0";
```

En esta línea, intentaría inicializar el algoritmo[17][11] cuando el arreglo,
en un problema de 3 reinas, no existe.

La aplicación falla, da un java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException,
pero no se cierra, por eso te la sensación de que no funciona bien.

La solución es arreglar la forma en que calculas la posición del ratón.
Tienes la posición del ratón, sólo necesitas saber la posición del JFrame,
y a partir de ahí hacer los cálculos.

En este enlace te indican cómo hacerlo:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950726/find-the-location-position-of-jframe-in-the-window

Espero que te sirva.

Comment: No creo que esta respuesta cumpla con lo que pido realmente, el problema que menciono es que al mover una reina en ocaciones no se posiciona correctamente en el arreglo y aunque las resinas esten bien acomodadas menciona que hay mas de una reina en una columna, fila o diagonal. La respuesta que planteas solo menciona la parte de las posiciones de las reinas en pantalla pero ese no es el punto del problema que planteo. Lo digo con todo respeto y espero que no te ofendas :)

Comment: Hola,  es recomendable brindar una solución o alternativa para solucionar el problema, no solo indicar cual es, en realidad si se puede cerrar la aplicación al generarse un ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, revisar [answer], saludos.

Comment: La excepción que indico, ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException, en la práctica no cierra la aplicación, pero hace que las reinas se posicionen mal.

Este comportamiento hace parecer que la aplicación tiene un problema de rendimiento, ocultando el problema real.

Comment: El problema real es el que he indicado, las reinas no se posicionan bien en la matriz, porque al algoritmo que calcula la posición le falta una variable, la posición del JFrame en pantalla.

La solución es la que indico en el enlace a StackOverflow.

Por ejemplo, el problema de las tres reinas.

Si el JFrame está en la posición X: 800px y el ratón en la posición X:1000 px, entonces el ratón está en la posición (1000px-800px) en la matriz. 

Cuando le pases 200px al algoritmo, te devolverá la posición real (0, 1 ó 2). Actualmente la pasa 1000px, dando posiciones incorrectas.